# How to refresh a webpage without browser asking to resend data again - Struts 2

Tags: post, struts2, page-refresh

I am getting the following error from browser that "To display this page, Firefox will repeat any action  that was performed earlier" when the user clicks on F5 and the form gets submitted again. I tried using POST REDIRECT GET but facing issues.

Below is my code:
   My original code was

```
  <action name="update-test" class="testAction" method="test">
  <result name="success">/test/xyz/test-result.jsp</result>
  </action>

 <action name="update-test" class="testAction" method="test">
<result name="success" type="redirectAction">forward-test</result>
 </action>
 <action name="forward-test" class="testAction" method="forward">
 <result name="success">/test/xyz/test-result.jsp</result>
  </action>


Apr 26, 2014 4:12:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
 java.lang.NullPointerException   at                                                                       org.apache.jsp.portal.tiles.tickets.tests_002test_002dresult_002dv1_jsp._jspService(tests_0    02dtest_002dresult_002dv1_jsp.java:196)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
```

When I did a view source on Line 196, I see the below.

```
<div id="tabXYZ" class="panel">
<img src="/images/arrow_mainmenu.jpg" width="25" height="31" alt="" class="floatingleft">
```

This is my entire file.
test_result.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<%@ page import="com.ubizen.og.reportcenter.site.StandardCollectionKeys"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

<tiles:insertTemplate template="/test/templates/testTemplate.jsp">
    <% pageContext.setAttribute("selectedModule", session.getAttribute(StandardCollectionKeys.SELECTED_MODULE)); %>
    <tiles:putAttribute name="header" type="string"><s:property value="#attr.selectedModule.label"/></tiles:putAttribute>
    <tiles:putAttribute name="body" value="/test/tiles/test/test-inspect-result-v1.jsp"/>
    <tiles:putAttribute name="showTopLink" value="true" type="string"/>
</tiles:insertTemplate>
```

Comment: Why do you think it's on line 196, also post `test-result.jsp` so we could see the original line.

Comment: I am unable to post the entire file in the comments box. Can I post it as an answer.

Comment: Set `struts.devMode=true` the error should be in the browser. And no, don't post an answer if you  have not it.

Comment: I turned on the devmode and this is what I see. Can you please let me know what could be causing this.                                 Struts Problem Report

Struts has detected an unhandled exception:
Messages:  

    JSPException including path '/portal/test/tickets/test-inspect-result-v1.jsp'.
   

File:  org/apache/jsp/portal/test/tickets/test_002dinspect_002dresult_002dv4_jsp.java
Line number:  196
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:430) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
Stacktraces

Comment: File:  org/apache/jsp/portal/tiles/test/test_002dinspect_002dresult_002dv1_jsp.java
Line number:  196

Comment: Ouch, it useless until you get the actual errornous line in jsp.

Comment: Can I post the file as an answer? As I am unable to update my original post.

Comment: Is it a correct path `/test/tiles/test/test-inspect-result-v1.jsp`? Also this code is required. And ofcourse you can't. When you have enough rep you can post more lines. So you have to edit your question and compact it.

Comment: The correct path is /test/tiles/tickets/test-inspect-result-v1.jsp , This file is too huge to be added in the comments

Comment: So, why don't you fix the path and check for errors?

Comment: The path is correct in the code, Sorry I was trying to modify it and post it in the forum. Within test-result.jsp, test-inspect-result-v1.jsp is included. I will edit it and post it if its not clear.

Comment: Is there any other way I can paste the entire code. please let me know.

Comment: use PostRedirectGet pattern or the history.pushState() trick

Answer (score 2):

In Struts2 Best way to prevent re-submission of form on refresh is to use `token` interceptor or `tokenSession` interceptor.

To use `token` interceptor add `<s:token>` tag inside form as given below.

```
<s:form action="yourAction" method="post">
    <s:token/>
    //your parameters or form fields
</s:form>
```

Using `token` Interceptor on re-submission of a form you can redirect user to the page you want(i.e `/invalid_token.jsp` here) as shown below.

configuration in your `struts.xml` for `token` interceptor is as follows

```
<action name="yourAction" class="com.YourActionClass">
    <interceptor-ref name="token"></interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
    <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/update.jsp</result>
    <result name="invalid.token">/invalid_token.jsp</result>
</action>
```

If you want to show a previous action's result page to the user on refreshing or resubmitting a form without calling action again, you can use `tokenSession` interceptor.

configuration in your `struts.xml` for `tokenSession` interceptor is as follows

```
<action name="yourAction" class="com.YourActionClass">
    <interceptor-ref name="tokenSession"></interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
    <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/update.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pravin. My scenario is that on page refresh the same page should be refreshed but the form should not be sunmitted and i only have a success.jsp and no input.jsp.Can I use token session interceptor in this case?

Comment: But why do you want to refresh the page without submitting the form? Are you going to get new data on refresh? Practically I don't think you will get new data unless submission of form.

Comment: If you are getting a same data as you have got after first time submission of form then...Yes.....tokenSession interceptor will definitely work for your scenario.